# When Tweeting my Wordpress post, how to get shortcode output to appear instead of shortcode text?

Tags: twitter, wordpress-shortcode

I use shortcodes on my WordPress site to help display reference information from my articles from a BibTeX file. For example, the article information at the top of [my post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/categorical-large-cardinals/) is generated this way, using a shortcode of the form `[bibtex key="id"]`, where id is the reference id in the BibTeX file. I am using the `papercite` plugin.

When I tweet this post, however, using the URL above, what I get instead is the shortcode text itself, instead of the shortcode output. See:

https://twitter.com/JDHamkins/status/1306124193357074433

Why is Twitter using the shortcode text here, and how to I get it to use the output text instead?

Comment: I don't seem to have the right to post images here, but I placed a screenshot at https://twitter.com/JDHamkins/status/1306142267854422016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source HTML, it has the lines

```
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
...
<meta property="og:description" content="[bibtex key=&#8221;HamkinsSolberg:Categorical-large-cardinals&#8221;]" />
...
<!-- End Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
```

So it looks like the Jetpack WP plugin doesn't process the shortcodes.

I'd suggest to add an introductory sentence at the top of the post, before the [bibtex] line. Like maybe a 1-sentence summary of the abstract?

**Update**: Apparently the Yoast SEO Plugin can be used to solve the issue, see https://randomneuronsfiring.com/jetpack-publicize-setting-the-image-and-text-shown-on-twitter-and-facebook/

Comment: Good idea. I think that will be an easy workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work after all. In my tweet https://twitter.com/JDHamkins/status/1308305279222652930 about my latest paper, I had put text before the shortcode in the blog post, but still Twitter grabbed the shortcode text instead of that introductory sentence.

Comment: @Joel, I edited the answer... you may try to use the Yoast SEO Plugin specifically to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It will be because Twitter uses the `<meta property="og:...">` tags in the header rather than using the page text:

```
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Categorical large cardinals and the tension between categoricity and set-theoretic reflection" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://jdh.hamkins.org/categorical-large-cardinals/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="[bibtex key=&#8221;HamkinsSolberg:Categorical-large-cardinals&#8221;]" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2020-09-16T06:50:00+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2020-09-16T06:50:04+00:00" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Joel David Hamkins" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://jdh.hamkins.org/wp-content/uploads/Categorical-cardinals-Venn-diagram.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="504" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="306" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@JDHamkins" />
<meta name="twitter:text:title" content="Categorical large cardinals and the tension between categoricity and set-theoretic reflection" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
```

JetPack offer some help — https://jetpack.com/tag/open-graph/ —  on how to manually alter what their open graph plugin does, but it may take some work